# How to use table lookup functions results as input for calculations?

Tags: org-mode, org-table, calc

I have the following static table:

```
#+name: static
|-------+---------------+-----+--------|
|       | Date of birth | Sex | Height |
|-------+---------------+-----+--------|
| Croce | <1985-07-30>  |   1 |    177 |
| Lilly | <1990-01-16>  |   0 |    154 |
|-------+---------------+-----+--------|
```

and I would like to produce the following table from it :

```
|-------+--------+------+------|
|       | Weight | BMI  | BFP  |
|-------+--------+------+------|
| Croce |   68.8 | 22   | 17.2 |
| Lilly |   48.2 | 20.3 | 24.4 |
|-------+--------+------+------|
```

- `Weight` value is inputted
- `BMI` value is computed with round($2*(10^4/`Height`^2),1)
- `BFP` value is computed with round(1.39*$3+0.16*((date(now())-date(`Date of birth`))/365)-10.34*`Sex`-9,1)

I managed to retrieve `Height`, `Date of birth` and `Sex` with `org-lookup-first` and `remote` (eg. `'(org-lookup-first $1 '(remote(static,@2$1..@>$1)) '(remote(static,@2$4..@>$4)))` for `Height`), but when I use the retrieved values in formula I got errors.

Example :
`$3=round($2*(10^4/'(org-lookup-first $1 '(remote(static,@2$1..@>$1)) '(remote(static,@2$4..@>$4)))^2),1)` doesn't work.

So I'm wondering how to use table lookup functions results as input for calculations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to extract a specific element from a vector with [mcol](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Extracting-Elements.html#index-mcol) (extract), [find](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Manipulating-Vectors.html#index-find) (a specific element) and [remote](https://orgmode.org/manual/References.html) (from a vector).

```
|-------+--------+------+------|
|       | Weight |  BMI |  BFP |
|-------+--------+------+------|
| Lilly |   48.2 | 20.3 | 24.4 |
| Croce |   68.8 |   22 | 17.2 |
| Croce |   69.4 | 22.2 | 17.5 |
|-------+--------+------+------|
#+TBLFM: $3=round($2*(10^4/mcol(remote(static,@2$4..@>$4),find(remote(static,@II$1..@III$1),$1))^2),1)
#+TBLFM: $4=round(1.39*$3+0.16*((date(now())-date(mcol(remote(static,@2$2..@>$2),find(remote(static,@II$1..@III$1),$1))))/365)-10.34*mcol(remote(static,@2$3..@>$3),find(remote(static,@II$1..@III$1),$1))-9,1)
```

Formula length can be reduced through the use of an additional column.

```
|-------+--------+---+------+------|
|       | Weight | i |  BMI |  BFP |
|-------+--------+---+------+------|
| Lilly |   48.2 | 2 | 20.3 | 24.4 |
| Croce |   68.8 | 1 |   22 | 17.2 |
| Croce |   69.4 | 1 | 22.2 | 17.5 |
|-------+--------+---+------+------|
#+TBLFM: $3=find(remote(static,@II$1..@III$1),$1)
#+TBLFM: $4=round($2*(10^4/mcol(remote(static,@2$4..@>$4),$3)^2),1)
#+TBLFM: $5=round(1.39*$4+0.16*((date(now())-date(mcol(remote(static,@2$2..@>$2),$3)))/365)-10.34*mcol(remote(static,@2$3..@>$3),$3)-9,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

When using actual Lisp expressions in a table formula, [all values are interpreted as strings](https://orgmode.org/manual/Formula-syntax-for-Lisp.html). There are some [mode options](https://orgmode.org/manual/Formula-syntax-for-Calc.html) that make it do otherwise, but because you're using strings *and* numbers *and* remote references your best option is probably `$3='(* (string-to-number $2) (/ 10000.0 (expt (string-to-number (org-lookup-first $1 '(remote(static,@2$1..@>$1)) '(remote(static,@2$4..@>$4)))) 2)));%.1f`

(Literal mode `;L` won't work, because it will attempt to treat your `remote $1` call as a list of variable names.) Note that the top-level expression a lisp s-exp; I don't think you can mix Lisp stuff into org-syntax (but I might not have tested this case thoroughly).

Comment: I understand... Then using Lisp expressions for calculation makes the formula quite verbose... Isn't there a Calc functionality equivalent to vlookup or join?

Comment: Seems unlikely, since the existence of such a thing would violate the abstraction barrier between Calc and Org. There's a [complete list of Calc functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Function-Index.html) you can peruse though; maybe you'll spot something I didn't.

Comment: I spotted `find` and `mcol` which did the job. Has the abstraction barrier been violated?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here I think is *not* the string conversions (which I admit *is* a problem - I have whined about it in the past), but the `remote` operation. When you specify a range of more than one cell for a `remote` operation, what you will get back is a *vector*: that will cause all sorts of problems since what you are trying to do is calculate an entry in the second table using a single corresponding entry in the other table.

The solution is to *not* do that, but specify exactly the cell in the remote table that you are interested in. There are examples of that in the [References](https://orgmode.org/org.html#References) section of the Tables/Spreadsheet chapter in the manual. The following example is found in the "Field Coordinates in Formulas" subsection:

```
’$2 = '(identity remote(FOO, @@#$1))’
     Copy text or values of each row of column 1 of the table named FOO
     into column 2 of the current table.
```

Note how you specify each row: `@@#` i.e. the row in the remote table whose row number is equal to the row number (`@#`) in the current table. Normally, you could say `@.` for that, but that only works when you are dealing with cells in the current table: it does *not* work for remote references. In general, relative cell specifications do *NOT* work in the remote case.

Given that, you can write the formulas in the second table like this:

```
#+name: static
|-------+---------------+-----+--------|
|       | Date of birth | Sex | Height |
|-------+---------------+-----+--------|
| Croce | <1985-07-30>  |   1 |    177 |
| Lilly | <1990-01-16>  |   0 |    154 |
|-------+---------------+-----+--------|



|-------+--------+--------------+------+------|
|       | Weight | Age in Years |  BMI |  BFP |
|-------+--------+--------------+------+------|
| Croce |   68.8 |    37.072070 |   22 | 17.2 |
| Lilly |   48.2 |    32.606636 | 20.3 | 24.4 |
|-------+--------+--------------+------+------|
#+TBLFM: $3 = (now() - remote(static, @@#$2)) /365.25
#+TBLFM: $4 = round($2 * pow(10, 4) / pow(remote(static, @@#$4),2), 1)
#+TBLFM: $5 = round(1.39*$4 + 0.16 * $3 - 10.34 * remote(static, @@#$3) - 9, 1)
```

Note that I prefer to add additional columns for intermediate calculations (in this case, the age in years): that simplified the last formula considerably. It also makes it easier to check the results.

I also split the three formulas into three separate `#+TBLFM` lines: if you prefer, you can string them together into one line with `::` separators. The latter is actually preferable: recalculating the table with `C-c *` or `C-u C-c *` does *NOT* work if the formulas are split.
The advantage of separate lines is only that they fit better in a display box on SE Emacs :-)

Finally, I arranged the evaluation so that the age is done first in the normal left-to-right, top-to-bottom evaluation order that the Org table code uses when recalculating tables. That way when we come to calculating the BFP, we already have the correct age in the second column. This was easy in this case, but there are cases, when you have to run the evaluation repeatedly in order for the calculations to converge. See [The Spreadsheet](https://orgmode.org/org.html#The-Spreadsheet) section of the manual for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I learned a lot. I didn't know about multiple `#+TBLFM:`. It is indeed more readable, but you have to `C-c` each line for a refresh. [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_fat_percentage#From_BMI) your BFP formula is less accurate. Your solution is quite nice, but it doesn't work if I put multiple values for an individual. I mean Croce's weight is 68.8 today, and tomorrow it will be 67.9. So he wants to have multiple lines in the output table to be able to graph the history (I should have specified that in the question...)

Comment: It means that the output table would have an additional input column for dates.

Comment: Well, I can only answer what you ask - not what's in the back of your mind :-)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you had two output tables, one for each person?

Comment: I edited the answer to add a caveat about putting `#TBLFM` formulas on separate lines: they break  the `C-c *` table recalculation functionality. It's better to string them on a single line.

Comment: To answer your question, I think that `vlookup` or `join` are quite useful, and in some cases necessary. So even if they could be avoided in my use case, I'd like to find a way to use them (if possible without constantly specifying  `string-to-number`)